# How does [UIView beginAnimations] work?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

I was wondering how animations work in Cocoa Touch.  For example:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

view1.alpha = 1.0;
view2.frame.origin.x += 100;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

How does `UIView` tracks the changes to the properties of the two views?

I suspect that KVO is used, but does it really observe the changes to every views between the  `beginAnimations` and `commitAnimations` calls?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simplified explanation:

All animations for all views are handled on a single stack, `beginAnimations:context:` will push a new active `CAAnimationGroup` on the stack, and `commitAnimations` will pop the current active animation group.

If there is an active animation group on the stack, then all setters for animatable properties will create `CAAnimation` subclass instances to handle that property and add then to the active animation group.

When the last animation is popped, it is replayed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just a wrapper over the old CoreAnimation calls. Look into the CoreGraphics API, you can see that there are multiple keys that you must set into a dictionary, while providing beginning and ending values for these keys.